# sort and remove duplicate lines in a sql log

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I am trying to sort and remove duplicate lines in bash script.

I have a sql log that outputs the sql statement and the execution time. I want remove lines that have the same sql statement and sort based on the execution time. Here are some samples lines

> ```
> tid=0xa3f] Query Executed in 881.3504 ms; rowCount = 0; 
> indexesUsed(1):Foo_trade(Results: 0) "select distinct * from fooTable
> where  IN SET($1,$2) and jobSource = $3 order by jobId asc"
>
> tid=0xa3h] Query Executed in 881.3504 ms; rowCount = 0;
> indexesUsed(1):Foo_trade(Results: 0) "select distinct * from fooTable 
> where  IN SET($1,$2) and jobSource = $3 order by jobId asc"
>
> tid=0xb38] Query Executed in 138.22551 ms; rowCount = 0; 
> indexesUsed(1):Foo_Job(Results: 0) "select distinct * from 
> Foo_Job where state IN SET($1,$2) and jobSource = $3 order by jobId asc"
> ```

goal:
to sort on same select statement to remove duplicates and then sort by execution time

Comment: I think you have some formatting problem in your sample data

Comment: Also, you say that you "want to remove lines that have the same sql statement" - I suppose you want to keep ONE of such lines. How do you want to choose which?

Comment: What have you tried? your `tid=` indexes are all *unique* so there would be no removal after `sort` even calling `uniq`. What would your output look like for the input you have given?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\" '{ match($1,/[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+/);sql[$2]=substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH) } END { for ( i in sql ) { print sql[i]" "i } }' sql.log | sort -k 1
```

Use awk to split the data with " as the delimiter. Store the sql queries in an array called sql, along with the query times. At the end, loop through the queries. As the sql query is the element of the array, the queries will be unique. Pipe the output through sort to sort the execution times.

Comment: thanks that takes care of the sorting by longest time but I also want to eliminate the same sql statement

Comment: to niglesias. Yes I want to keep the line with the highest time and remove the others

Comment: I've changed the solution to give the data required.